# How can I compare the multiline parameter in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a feature file with step

```
Then I must see the specific text 'Lorem ipsum.\r\nLorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem ipsum\r\nLorem ipsum.' in the text .error-message block on the page
```

And step definition

```
    [Then(@"I must see the specific text '(.*)' in the text (.*) block on the page")]
    public void ThenISeeTheSpecificTextOnThePage(string expectedText, string textBlockName)
    {
        var actualText = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(textBlockName)).Text;
        ///var removeCaret = actualText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
        Assert.Contains(expectedText, actualText);
    }
```

Every time I run this step in debug I see the output

```
> Assert.Contains() Failure
Not found: Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum
In value:  Lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
```

I know that I can trim `\r\n` and adapt my input parameter in the feature file. But this would be a hack, which I don't want to do. Is there any chance to assert multiline text?

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere? Your step does not contain a comma anywhere, but your example does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Doc Strings](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Gherkin/Gherkin-Reference.html#doc-strings) for specifying your string parameter:

```
Then I must see the specific text in the .error-message block on the page:
    """
    Lorem ipsum.
    Lorem ipsum, lorem ipsum - lorem ipsum
    Lorem ipsum.
    """
```

And using the following step definition:

```
[Then(@"I must see the specific text in the (.*) block on the page:")]
public ThenIMustSeeTheSpecificTextInTheBlockOnThePage(string textBlockName, string expectedText)
{
    var actualText = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(textBlockName)).Text;

    Assert.Contains(expectedText, actualText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Greg. You made my day! The only thing is the spaces. When I compare the actual text with the expected one, `Assert.Contains` provides me an error message because two text blocks are not the same. I copy the exact out from the debugger. No luck.